# Is $A(x,y)=1$ the only solution?

Tags: functions

Suppose we define $x_k=a+\frac kN$ with the constraint that $x_N=(b-a)$ for all naturals $0\leq k\leq N$, so that we have $N$ equidistant points starting at $a$ and ending in $b$.

I need to find a function $A:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$, such that for all $a<b\in\Bbb R$, all $N\in\Bbb N$ and in the limit $N\to\infty$ the following must hold:

$$A(a,b)=\prod_{k=0}^N A(x_k, x_{k+1})$$

I think that the only function satisfying this is the function $A(x,y)=1$, but I have no clue where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What about $A(x,y) = e^{y-x}$?

Comment: $A$ is a real valued function

Comment: So is $e^{y-x}$, restricted to $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: @AlexSilva Oh sorry I read an $i$ somewhere.